# Cannot install latest version of a package

Tags: 16.04, package-management, upgrade, repository, aptitude

I would like to install the latest version of a package called `libqt5core5a`.

I ve checked the [Ubuntu Repository website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libqt5core5a) and there is a version I am interested in.

Let's check the current installed version of that package:

```
  userk@dopamine:~$ sudo apt-cache policy libqt5core5a

  libqt5core5a:
  Installed: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.6
  Candidate: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.6
  Version table:
  *** 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.6 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

I ve tried a quick

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Checked again the installed version and noticed that no upgrade occured.

Tried then with a more specific request and got a not found error...

```
$ sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a=5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1' for 'libqt5core5a' was not found
```

Checking again other commands to see the latest available version on the remote repository and:

```
$ aptitude versions libqt5core5aPackage 

libqt5core5a:                        
p   5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7                     xenial                500 
i   5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.6                   xenial-security,xenia 500 

Package libqt5core5a:i386:
p   5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7                     xenial                500 
p   5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.6                   xenial-security,xenia 500
```

How do I install a specific version of a package on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Comment: That version is available in the disco repositories which are 19.04.  You are running 16.04.  Adding the repositories from newer versions can break the distro that you are currently running so if you need that version you might want to consider upgrading your distro.

Comment: Do not run `apt-cache policy` with `sudo`.

Comment: Reading it. Thanks

Comment: Because it is not necessary, and you should only use `sudo` when necessary.